# How to do styling in react native which makes app UI consistent over all types of mobile phone sizes

Tags: react-native, styling

I have built an app in react native ,I have used dimensions in react native to get the screen size of phone for styling purpose still its not working properly for some handsets.My UI looks shabby on some phones.Did i missed out something other than dimensions property and also can anyone tell me how to place components which looks consistent over all size of phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what flexbox is for: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

It allows your components to be positioned and sized proportionally to the amount of space available on the device.

Comment: Okay..some people use a technique to set a width like width*0.2 , what's this is for???

Comment: Width is the whole device width

Comment: You can set each component to have a proportional width, a container with flex:1, and a child of flex : .2 for example